# I have an error when I run it, how do I fix it?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

```
import speech_recognition
Robot_ear = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
    print("Robot: I'm listening")
    audio = Robot_ear.Listen(mic)

you = Robot_ear.Recognizer_google(audio)
print(you)
```

And I have an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\code\nghe.py", line 5, in 
audio = Robot_ear.Listen(mic)
AttributeError: 'Recognizer' object has no attribute 'Listen'

Comment: The message is saying that `speech_recognition.Recognizer()` has no attribute Listen. Did you check the library documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated code:

```
import speech_recognition
Robot_ear = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
    print("Robot: I'm listening")
    audio = Robot_ear.listen(mic)

you = Robot_ear.recognize_google(audio)
print(you)
```

I'll explain your errors,

1. First go through the documentation before you go to the programming
2. The errors are:

   a)Use small letter in `Listen` i.e `listen`

   b) Use small letter in `Recognize.google()` i.e `recognize.google()`

Answer (score 0):

```
import speech_recognition
Robot_ear = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
    print("Robot: I'm listening")
    audio = Robot_ear.listen(mic)

you = Robot_ear.Recognizer_google(audio)
print(you)
```

Use a lower case "l" instease. `listen`